# using robobrowser for clicking through lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a browser from which I need to scrape data.

On that page, I have multiple lists and in those lists I need to select each element by turn and then get on the next page so this is basically multiple iteration of lists.

To start with, I tried to iterate through the first list.

My code is as follows:

```
 soup1=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')

 for link in soup1.find_all(class_="combo").find_all('option'):

     link.click()
```

or should I use robobrowser for clicking on links:

browser.follow_link(browser.find(class_="combo").find_all('option'))

It shows up as an error because it says that result set has no attribute as find_all

Comment: you can't do like `soup1.find_all(class_="combo").find_all('option')` because `soup1.find_all(class_="combo")` it gives a list of element.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara Okay, I have put it separately now. How should I click on it?

Comment: need to check in HTML content. can you please check there is multiple class `combo` and, for each one class how much `option` class is available?

Comment: @ManaliKagathara this is the link of the website. https://www.ine.es/censo/es/seleccion_inframunicipal.jsp

Comment: @ManaliKagathara the problem is that I have multiple lists that I need to click through.

Answer (score 0):

try this to click on the option of `Comunidades Autónomas` table in the website.

```
soup1=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
Comunidades_table = soup1.find_all(class_="combo")[0]

for link in Comunidades_table.find_all(class_="option"):
     link.click()
```